# assert before cast - ClassCastException or AssertionError?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

Is there any sense in doing something like this:

```
Object object = getSomeObject();
assert object instanceof ClassA;
ClassA a = (ClassA) object;
```

I know that if `object` is not a `ClassA` instance, then a `ClassCastException` will happen anyway.

Would there be any use of using the former mentioned type of error signaling?

Comment: They're not quite the same - if `object` is null, the assert will fire (the result of `instanceof` will be `false`) but the cast would have succeeded.

Comment: That sounds like the answer right there, would there be any other functionality, other than the null check, that you know of?

Comment: Only that it will change which error is thrown, as you've already noted.

Comment: Given the fact that catching RuntimeExceptions or AssertionErrors sounds like a bad idea, I don't see how that would help much. Thanks @Jon Skeet